# gensim - Doc2Vec: Difference iter vs. epochs

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

When reading the [Doc2Vec documentation of gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), I get a bit confused about some options. For example, the constructor of Doc2Vec has a parameter *iter*:

> iter (int) – Number of iterations (epochs) over the corpus.

Why does the train method then also have a similar parameter called *epochs*?

> epochs (int) – Number of iterations (epochs) over the corpus.

What is the difference between both? There's one more paragraph on it in the docs:

> To avoid common mistakes around the model’s ability to do multiple
>   training passes itself, an explicit epochs argument MUST be provided.
>   In the common and recommended case, where train() is only called once,
>   the model’s cached iter value should be supplied as epochs value.

But I do not really understand why the constructor needs a *iter* parameter and what exactly should be provided for it.

**EDIT**:

I just saw that there is also the possibility to specify the corpus directly in the constructor rather than calling train() separately. So I think in this case, *iter* would be used and otherwise *epochs*. Is that correct?

If so, what is the difference between specifying the corpus in the constructor and calling train() manually? Why would one choose the one or other?

**EDIT 2**:

Although not mentioned in the docs, *iter* is now depreciated as parameter of Doc2Vec. It was renamed to *epochs* to be consistent with the parameter of *train()*. Training seems to work with that, although I struggle with [MemoryErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390455/gensim-doc2vec-memoryerror-when-training-on-english-wikipedia).

Comment: Seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807010/what-are-doc2vec-training-iterations/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47025885/712995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter in the constructor was originally called `iter`, and when doing everything via a single constructor call – supplying the corpus in the constructor – that value would just be used as the number of training passes.

When the parameters to `train()` were expanded and made mandatory to avoid common errors, the term `epochs` was chosen as more descriptive, and distinct from the `iter` value.

When you specify the corpus in the constructor, `build_vocab()` and `train()` will be called for you automatically, as part of the construction. For most simple uses, that's fine.

But, if you let those automatic calls happen, you lose the chance to time the steps separately, or to tamper with results of the vocabulary steps before starting training, or to call `train()` multiple times (which is usually a bad idea unless you're sure you know what you're doing).